# Using Scanner to scan through a predefined list of strings in another class, and parse them to Ints in java

Tags: java

Quite a few labs have passed since my previous request for some advice and we are nearing midterms quite quickly! I am currently working on another lab right now and have ran into some slight difficulty that a little advice or guidance might help! Anyways here is whats going on!

I must have 3 classes in total:
(StationRecordMain, StationRecord, and TemperatureData)

He gave us the TemperatureData class pre-written and not able to modify it in anyway. This class holds a huge array of Strings all looking like this

"14762 20180829 89 70 80 9.6" . These are some junk number in the beginning we must throw away, the year month and day, the high temp, the low temp, avg, and difference.

This prewritten class also holds 2 methods in it, (hasNextTempRecord, getNextTempRecord).

My StationRecord class holds the following instance variables:

```
private int yearMonthDay = 0;
private int max = 0;
private int min = 0;
private int avg = 0;
private double dif = 0;
```

Finally, my MainStationRecord class holds the Scanner Object:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(tempdata.getNextTempRecord());
```

, an attempt to use the scanner to read through the predefined strings in the other class.

Anyways, I can supply more code that I have written but didnt want to flood this page with all of it, but those are the basics. I believe I am at a points where I know what I need to do, just need some guidance.

I need to use the Scanner to scan through all of those Strings on the other class (there are like 100 of them, so i'm assuming some sort of loop somewhere)
Then, I need to piece out each one of those strings and store their values in those private instance variables. Finally parsing them to ints and printing them out in the main class. That is where I am lost. Ive never used a scanner in such a way to do a preset of defined strings in a different class, moreover I have no experience on how to chop them up or parse them really.

Thus, if anyone could guide me in the right direction, It would be greatly appreciated! As I said before I can post the rest of my code I have written to make things easier if need be!

Until then thank you for looking!

Comment: if I understand, you can use your scanner and something like this scan.nextInt() to easily get next int without getting string and parse it to int later

Comment: *"i'm assuming some sort of loop somewhere"* Correct, a loop similar to how a `Scanner` works, e.g. `while (sc.hasNext()) { String str = sc.next(); /*code*/ }`, or an `Iterator` works, e.g. `while (iter.hasNext()) { String str = iter.next(); /*code*/ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if I understand it, You can easily do something like this: (I don't have complete code of yours, so this is just a suggestion)

```
class StationRecord  {
    private int yearMonthDay = 0;
    private int max = 0;
    private int min = 0;
    private int avg = 0;
    private double dif = 0;

    public StationRecord(int yearMonthDay, int max, int min, int avg, double dif) {
        this.yearMonthDay = yearMonthDay;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        this.avg = avg;
        this.dif = dif;
    }

    // rest of your code
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        // rest of your codes
        while (tempdata.hasNextTempRecord()) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(tempdata.getNextTempRecord());
            scan.next(); // read until a space and I don't save it for throw it away
            new StationRecord(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble()); 
        }  
        // rest of your codes  
    }
}
```

Thanks Andreas for comments too. This is what I understand and write it.

Comment: Missing the skipping of the first value, and the entire point of looping through all the temperature data.

Comment: The `while` condition is mentioned in the question.

Comment: I read the first part very fast and last part completely. the last part only say about give an idea how to that, So I give an example. but thanks for mention that too.

Comment: @Amin Yes! that looks about right. Very good example, right on track to the rest of where my code was headed aswell! Very clever on the throw away part aswell. I will try to implement something similar into my code in the morning and give it another go. If I get caught up on that same issue of implementation I will post back here with an updated piece of the code. Thank you very much! Sorry that I wont know until morning >.<